# Are global complete intersections locally complete intersections?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00S8 a global complete intersection is defined to be a ring of the form $R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(f_1,\ldots,f_c)$ of Krull dimension $n-c$. Is such a ring locally a complete intersection? I.e. if $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal, is then $R_\mathfrak{m}$ a local complete intersection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension of a ring is the supremum of the local dimensions. Hence, $\dim R_\mathfrak{m} \leq n-c$ for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}$. On the other hand, 
$$R_{\mathfrak{m}} = k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]_{\mathfrak{m}}/(f_1,\ldots, f_c),$$
and $\dim k[x_1,\ldots, x_m]_{\mathfrak{m}} = n$ again,
so again $R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is a complete intersection.

Comment: yes, as explained on the webpage that I linked in the question, the dimension of the localization at a maximal ideal is still $n-c$. Why does that imply that the localization is a complete intersection?

Comment: Because the localization is the quotient of a dimension $n$ ring by the $c$ elements $f_1, \ldots, f_c$ (or, if you like, their images in $k[x_1, \ldots, x_m]_{\mathfrak{m}}$).